# Netezza SQL: Specify an offset in a window frame

Tags: sql, window, netezza, partition

When making the "frame" for a windowed analytic function, one can specify a literal number of rows to "look back" over.  E.g., the following will get the trailing 26 weeks weekly sales for a households.

```
,sum(sales) over (partition by household_id order by week_id rows 26 preceding) as x26
```

But... what if you wanted to look back (or forward) with an offset?  E.g., if for week n, you wanted the sales for the 26 weeks that ended 8 weeks before week n?  As I was typing this, it occurred to me that I could probably do it in parts.  I.e.,

```
 ,sum(sales) over (partition by household_id order by week_id rows 34 preceding) as x34
 ,sum(sales) over (partition by household_id order by week_id rows 8 preceding) as x8
```

...and have `trailing26_offeset8 = x34 - x8`

Hm... Glad I asked.  But anyway, do you know if there's an feature that will let me specify the offset right in the partition specification itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `between` in the window range specification:

```
sum(sales) over (partition by household_id
                 order by week_id
                 rows between 34 preceding and 8 preceding
                ) as x34
```

Comment: Yes, that works and was just what I was looking for!  FWIW, my two-part solution came up with the same answer, but this is certainly simpler.  Thanks.